# Why does reassigning unique_ptr increases memory usage?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, unique-ptr

I have a base class, and some polymorphs of it. I want to be able to create an object of type class base, and then morph it to class derived, and back to base. Can one do this? I am doing it as follows, but I am not sure this is the right approach:

Assuming I have these classes:

```
class base {
public:
    int var;
    base();
    virtual ~base();
    virtual void func1();
    void func2();
}

class derived1 : base {
public:
    unique_ptr<otherClass> otherVar;
    vector<unique_ptr<anotherClass>> myVec;
    derived1();
    ~ derived1() {
    otherVar.reset();
    for (unsigned int i=0; i< myVec.size(); i++) {
    myVec[i].reset();
    }
    myVec.clear();
    vector<unique_ptr< anotherClass >>().swap(myVec);
    }
    void  func1(){
       //do something
    }
}

class derived2 : base {
public:
    derived2();
    ~ derived2();
    void  func1(){
       //do something else
    }
}
```

Now somewhere else in code I do this:

```
  unique_ptr<base> myObject;
  myObject = unique_ptr< derived1 > (new derived1());
```

If later I do this:

```
  myObject.reset();
  myObject = unique_ptr< base > (new base());
```

the heap memory increases significantly. What is the reason, and how can one avoid this problem?

**Edit1**

I added more detail to derived1.
I get no errors, and the program runs without problem, only memory goes up when myObject morphs.
BTW, myObject never goes out of scope, it only changes its shape (so I am not actually sure that I am using the right kind of pointer).

**Edit2**

I managed to get rid of most of the pointers inside classes (unfortunately I can't use normal variables in all cases), and now I have very little memory growth.
But my understanding was that use of smart pointers should make life easier not harder. Is there any kind of pointer in C++ that we can use, free the memory without deleting it (I thought reset() is supposed to do that) and then reassign some other value to it later?

I must say though, for simple object this can be done by unique_ptr, but for complicated classes (that have pointers to other classes as their member variables), it seems that some of the memory never gets freed even after calling reset().

**Edit3**

I found out that the problem was not with the C++ part of the code, but with the OpenGL part. Sorry for confusing experts here XD.

While I was doing this:

```
    otherVar.reset();
```

this otherVar contained OpenGL textures. The destructor of this object was supposed to delete all the textures at once (on the Mac at least) with this call:

```
glDeleteTextures(textureCount, textures);
```

but on iOS (OpenGL ES), I had to delete the textures individually, like so:

```
glDeleteTextures(1, &tex.textureID);
```

Still, I have no idea why glDeleteTextures(textureCount, textures) doesn't delete all the textures at once in the iOS app, but at least I found a kind of workaround for it.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: You allocate a new object and wonder why your computer allocates memory for it?

Comment: `Now somewhere else in code I do this:`  `If later I do this:`  So I guess this means you can't duplicate this issue with a simple 3 or 4 line program.  You say "somewhere else" and "later I do", which indicates your program is much larger than what you're showing us.  Maybe what you're *not* showing us is contributing this behavior.

Comment: After re-assigning the memory gets big. I expect that reset() frees some memory, but it seems that it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: How do you know your heap size increased significantly and how do you define significantly?

Comment: @DARKMATTER How are you determining that the memory is not deallocated?  Hopefully it isn't by using OS tools such as Task Manager or similar program.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie: yes, the program is actually very large and the classes are more complicated. But as I mentioned I expect that reset() frees the memory, or maybe I am confused about what reset() is supposed to do.

Comment: I use Xcode's instruments to track memory allocations.

Comment: @DARKMATTER The C++ heap manager does not work this way, where there is a 1 to 1 relationship between memory allocations/deallocations and what the OS reports.  The heap is smart enough to not deallocate memory if there may be another request later on.

Comment: @DARKMATTER - As to not posting a self-contained program that demonstrates the error, take the program here:  http://ideone.com/a8JV59 and see if that duplicates your issue.

Comment: Well *nix system does memory allocation called "paging". The system does not just allocate 1 byte when you ask for 1 byte. It allocates a whole page (which is quite a few bytes depending on your system) if the current pages are full.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to be sure, but I suspect there may be a cyclic ownership pattern in your code.  Here is what that looks like in a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct B;
struct C;

struct A
{
    std::unique_ptr<B> b_ptr_;

    ~A();
};

struct B
{
    std::unique_ptr<C> c_ptr_;

    ~B();
};

struct C
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a_ptr_;

    ~C();
};


A::~A()
{
    std::cout << "~A()\n";
}

B::~B()
{
    std::cout << "~B()\n";
}

C::~C()
{
    std::cout << "~C()\n";
}

int
main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a_ptr(new A);
    a_ptr->b_ptr_ = std::unique_ptr<B>(new B);
    a_ptr->b_ptr_->c_ptr_ = std::unique_ptr<C>(new C);
    a_ptr->b_ptr_->c_ptr_->a_ptr_ = std::move(a_ptr);
}
```

When compiled and run, this program has no output.  That is worrisome as the destructors for `A`, `B` and `C` are not run, indicating a memory leak.

There are many ways to fix cyclic ownership.  But the first step is in understanding your memory ownership graph, and assuring that it is acyclic, and with `unique_ptr`, one must also assure that any node in the graph has only one (owning) parent node.

Here is one way to break the ownership cycle for this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct B;
struct C;

struct A
{
    std::unique_ptr<B> b_ptr_;

    ~A();
};

struct B
{
    std::unique_ptr<C> c_ptr_;

    ~B();
};

struct C
{
    A* a_ptr_;

    ~C();
};


A::~A()
{
    std::cout << "~A()\n";
}

B::~B()
{
    std::cout << "~B()\n";
}

C::~C()
{
    std::cout << "~C()\n";
}

int
main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a_ptr(new A);
    a_ptr->b_ptr_ = std::unique_ptr<B>(new B);
    a_ptr->b_ptr_->c_ptr_ = std::unique_ptr<C>(new C);
    a_ptr->b_ptr_->c_ptr_->a_ptr_ = a_ptr.get();
}
```

which correctly outputs:

```
~A()
~B()
~C()
```

I.e. insert a non-owning "raw pointer" into the cycle.  One could also use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` to break the cycle:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct B;
struct C;

struct A
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b_ptr_;

    ~A();
};

struct B
{
    std::shared_ptr<C> c_ptr_;

    ~B();
};

struct C
{
    std::weak_ptr<A> a_ptr_;

    ~C();
};


A::~A()
{
    std::cout << "~A()\n";
}

B::~B()
{
    std::cout << "~B()\n";
}

C::~C()
{
    std::cout << "~C()\n";
}

int
main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr(new A);
    a_ptr->b_ptr_ = std::shared_ptr<B>(new B);
    a_ptr->b_ptr_->c_ptr_ = std::shared_ptr<C>(new C);
    a_ptr->b_ptr_->c_ptr_->a_ptr_ = std::move(a_ptr);
}

~A()
~B()
~C()
```

Should I be mistaken that cyclic ownership is the culprit in your case, your time will not be completely wasted by reviewing, understanding and documenting the ownership paths in your code.

Comment: Thanks Howard, but there is no cyclic ownership in the code. The app runs perfectly on the Mac, but the iOS version crashes after running for some time due to gradual memory growth. It is an OpenGL ES graphics intensive app, so I really can't overlook memory problems.